# How to find accounts without primary holder

Tags: sql

I have a table with account number, customers number and is primary flag (0 or 1). Account will have 1 or more customers. What function I can use to pull all accounts from table where account does NOT have primary on account. So example account # 12345  has 3 customers but all customers have 0 as primary flag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest aggregation:

```
select account_number
from accounts a 
group by account_number
having max(is_primary) = 0;
```